# Probability related to circle

Tags: probability

Let we have to select point nearer to center then the circumference of a given circle.

What is the probability of finding such points?

I am confused that points at distance$\frac{r}{2}$must be favorable or not

Comment: The probability of what?

Comment: The points at distance $r/2$ won't change anything since the probability of being exactly at that distance is zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a circle with centre as $O$ and radius $OA = r$ cm. Make another concentric circle OB of radius $\frac{r}{2}$ cm. Any point interior to circle with radius $r$ cm is closer to the center than to circumference. If we choose a point at random, probability that it will lie in the inner circle is :- [image]$$\frac{\text{Area of Inner Circle}}{\text{Total area}} = \frac{\pi \times \frac{r}{2}\times \frac{r}{2}}{\pi\times r\times r} =\frac{1}{4}$$